# Sorting Ms Access tables records and VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

i've implemented a system on vb.net 2010 having its database on Ms Access 2010 (.accdb). i have to read records from the tables to a combo box by binding its datasource to the tables directly. the problem is that the data in the combo box is not sorted since in the database itself the records are not sorted. how can i achieve the sorting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ORDER BY` clause of the `SELECT` statement: [ORDER BY Clause](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/order-by-clause-HP001032258.aspx)

Comment: where can i access this? given that i did not use SQL to read data from the MS Access tables. i used data binding source :S

Comment: Relational database tables are inherently unsorted.  If you are binding to the tables directly you should not expect the data to be sorted.  This applies not only to Access, but also Oracle, Postgres, MySQL, SQLite, etc.  If you want the data sorted, a SQL query will be the most efficient way to do it by far.

Comment: yeah, i know but i thought that there was a solution apart from using SQL query. my bad :( anyways, thnx ;)